# Stretch a row if data overflows in jasper reports

Tags: java, jasper-reports, report, itext

how do i stretch a row when data overflows the band height in jasper reports, I have set the stretch with overflow flag as true but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 11):

I ran into this problem myself. I could not get the detail band to stretch, even though the text field in the band was configured to do so. The problem was with the report's **Print Order** property, which for some reason had been set to **horizontal**. When I changed it to **vertical**, the problem went away.

According to the JasperReports Ultimate Guide,

> When filling report templates horizontally, dynamic text fields inside
>   the detail section no longer stretch to their entire text content,
>   because this might cause misalignment on the horizontal axis of
>   subsequent detail sections.

Answer (score 5):

My band stretches if necessary with the following conditions, I do not know yours.
I have started with the ireport 1.0 netbeans plug-in and jasper 3.5.2.
The Split type for the band has been set to Stretch.

```
<band height="108" splitType="Stretch"></band>
```

The Stretch with overflow for the field has been checked, e.g.:

```
<textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
    <reportElement positionType="Float" x="70" y="28" width="485" height="14"/>
        <textElement>
            <font size="10"/>
        </textElement>
        <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[($F{EQUIPMENTS} == null ? "-" : $F{EQUIPMENTS})]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply..., I use Ireport 2.0.5 to generate jrxml file and use the same in my java web propject, I have used all the flags to stretch to fit the data, but it doesn't work...

Comment: The textfield to be stretched..

<textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true" evaluationTime="Now" hyperlinkType="None"  hyperlinkTarget="Self" >
     <reportElement
      style="dNew"
      mode="Opaque"
      x="55"
      y="0"
      width="55"
      height="19"
      key="value-1"
      stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject"
      positionType="Float"
      isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true"/>
     <box></box>
     <textElement>
      <font/>
     </textElement>
    <textFieldExpression   class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{value1}]]></textFieldExpression>
    </textField>

Comment: 2.0.5 is fairly old, so you may try it with a newer version.

Answer (score 0):

isn't that set the height enough tall, and the property overflow, then it will automatically overflow to multiple rows? such solution works for me.